# How do I know if a motherboard's onboard audio will be compatible with games?

Tags: audio, motherboard, computer-building, gaming

I'm planning on building a PC in the next couple of weeks. Currently I'm thinking that for my motherboard I'll buy an [ASUS Maximus VI Gene](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VI_GENE/) with [SupremeFX](http://rog.asus.com/technology/rog-sound-innovations/supremefx/), but I'm worried that I'll need a sound card for some of the games I want to play. For example:

- Watchdogs supposedly [requires](http://www.ign.com/wikis/watch-dogs/PC_System_Requirements) a DirectX 9.0c compatible sound card.
- Dishonored supposedly [requires](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:JAlbor/Dishonored_PC_System_Requirements) a "Windows compatible sound card"
- Call of Duty: Ghosts supposedly [requires](http://www.geforce.com/games-applications/pc-games/call-of-duty-ghosts/system-requirements) a DirectX Compatible sound card

So, do I really need a sound card? If not, how can I tell if any given motherboard's onboard audio will be compatible with a given game?

Comment: You don't. Onboards are more than capable and will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be hard pressed to find a non-DirectX sound card these days.  However, I could not find any documentation as to what level of DirectX it supports.  I would bet it is DirectX11 due its newness.

You should have no issues with onboard sound cards.  Some do use the motherboard's CPU for some processing, but with the speed of modern PCs, its not noticeable.